# Unable to login to website using PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to automate the login to the website but it doesn't work for me. Could it be due to nested DIVs? When I see in DOM explorer it has multiple DIV class and the code starts with:

```html
<form name="aspnetForm" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
```

PS script:

```bsh
$username = "username" 
$password = "password" 
$IE = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$url = "myurl"
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.Navigate("$url")
$IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_UserName").Value = "$username"
$IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_Password").Value = "$password"
$IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_ButtonSubmit").Submit();

Start-Sleep -s 5
```

Comment: If you're trying to work with Service Now, it has an API and you'd be much better off using that for logging in / doing what you need with it!

Comment: Wait for IE to finish loading the page: `while ($IE.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}`.

Comment: Are you sure it has a Submit() method/function? use a get-member on it, maybe its click() ?